# "No item with the given ID could be found"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-api

I am attempting to use a Google script to automatically make a copy of a sheet, place that into a specific folder and rename it.

Here is the script:

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("test"); 

    DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("test", destFolder);

} //END function saveAsSpreadsheet
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have
>   permission to access it. (line 4, file "Code")

The "test" folder is in the same folder as the sheet/script, so I'm wondering if this has to do with permissions, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the DriveApp.getFolderById() but passing a string of the name of the folder not the id. Therefore no item with the given ID can be found.

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer.